# Granger causality in non stationary VAR(1) process

Tags: stationarity, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

I have VAR(1) process which is not stationary (roots are outside of the unit circle). If I deemed it to be stationary, what can I say about Granger causality?

Comment: Let me see if I understand the question. You have a nonstationary VAR. You want to pretend it is stationary and then analyze Granger causality. Why do you want to pretend? What are you trying to achieve (what is your end goal)?

Comment: Yes, you understood my question correctly. I am trying to understand the principles of VAR and Grander causality. Is it useful to pretend my process is stationary in terms of Grander causality? And can I do a Granger causality test at all for such a process?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful, consider accepting it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

The general problem is, if your modeling assumptions diverge from reality, your results will, too. Concretely, in your example the coefficient estimators will not have their usual distributions due to nonstationarity. Now, Granger causality test is based on the estimated coefficients. Hence, the test statistic will not have its usual distribution under the null. This will affect the size of the test; the actual size will differ from the nominal size. You could simulate and see precisely how big of a problem this is.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing, you might be able to adjust your var-model to have a meaningful result. The most common way is to use the differences. However, if you want to calculate the Granger causality between the levels, you can also use the method as described by Yota and Yamamoto. This would result in you adding 1 additional lag to your model.